# Tuning LSTM autoencoder performance

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I am trying to build an autoencoder of a multidimensional time series. I have followed various templates around the internet and SO, but all of them focus on how to get it running, but haven't found one on how to get running and get some meaningful results.

I've followed the tutorials starting here: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html; a practical example here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-autoencoders/.

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, RepeatVector
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this sequence comes out of a MinMaxScaler. A separate question is if this was a good idea?
sequence = np.array([[0.63306452, 0.00714286],
       [0.42069892, 0.        ],
       [0.36155914, 0.15      ],
       [0.53629032, 0.12142857],
       [0.32526882, 0.24285714],
       [0.26344086, 0.52142857],
       [0.        , 0.79285714],
       [0.49731183, 0.71428571],
       [0.60080645, 0.25714286],
       [0.63037634, 0.11428571],
       [0.70698925, 0.26428571],
       [0.71774194, 0.21428571],
       [0.6155914 , 0.10714286],
       [0.56451613, 0.36428571],
       [0.66397849, 0.2       ],
       [0.76344086, 0.17857143],
       [0.66801075, 0.07142857],
       [0.66935484, 0.02857143],
       [0.90725806, 0.32857143],
       [1.        , 0.28571429],
       [1.        , 0.4       ],
       [0.81451613, 0.47857143],
       [0.41532258, 0.52142857],
       [0.55107527, 0.63571429],
       [0.42741935, 0.40714286],
       [0.56989247, 0.75      ],
       [0.76075269, 0.55      ],
       [0.69758065, 0.58571429],
       [0.73521505, 0.89285714],
       [0.77150538, 1.        ]])

n_in = len(sequence)
dim_in = sequence.shape[1]
latent_dim = 10
sequence = sequence.reshape((1, n_in, dim_in))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(latent_dim, input_shape=(n_in, dim_in)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_in))
model.add(LSTM(dim_in, return_sequences=True))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

model.fit(sequence, sequence, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

yhat = model.predict(sequence, verbose=0)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(sequence[0, :, 0])
plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(yhat[0, :, 0])
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(sequence[0, :, 1])
plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(yhat[0, :, 1])
```

The result I'm getting is not satisfactory (actuals in the upper row; autoencoder output in the lower row):
[image: Actuals (upper row); autoencoder output (lower row)]

The decoded series are missing important features (like the spike in the RHS or drop on the LHS. Given the 'compression ratio' of 30:10 I would expect those events to be somehow reflected. I've tried playing with epochs, batch sizes, various activations and losses.

1. Anything obvious I am missing?
2. I want to run it on a much larger sequence (5000 time points, each point of potentially high dimension). Any tips for this?
3. should I change my approach altogether? The Author of this blog post https://towardsdatascience.com/autoencoders-for-the-compression-of-stock-market-data-28e8c1a2da3e didn't make it work with LSTM as well...